submitting array using react hook form and react server actions
I'm trying to submit an array for a field called services using reack-hook-form but it's returning as a separate value when submitted. { customerId: '', title: '', message: '', serviceAt: '', 'services.0.id': '1', amount: '5.25' }
This works if I change it to use the onSubmit method but I want to use the actions method so the form can be used with JS.
"use client";

import { CaretSortIcon, CheckIcon, PlusIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";
import { useMutation, useQuery, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { CalendarIcon } from "lucide-react";
import { useReducer, useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import { toast } from "sonner";
import { z } from "zod";

import { Button } from "app/components/ui/button";
import { Calendar } from "app/components/ui/calendar";
import {
    Command,
    CommandEmpty,
    CommandGroup,
    CommandInput,
    CommandItem,
    CommandList,
} from "app/components/ui/command";
import { FullScreenModal } from "app/components/ui/full-screen-modal";
import { InputField } from "app/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "app/components/ui/label";
import {
    Popover,
    PopoverContent,
    PopoverTrigger,
} from "app/components/ui/popover";
import { Separator } from "app/components/ui/separator";
import { Textarea } from "app/components/ui/textarea";
import ServiceField from "../../components/ServiceField";

import createCustomerByName from "app/actions/mutations/createCustomerByName";
import { createProposalMutation } from "app/actions/mutations/createProposal";
import getCustomersQuery from "app/actions/queries/getCustomers";
import { useSlyderzForm } from "app/hooks/useSlyderzForm";
import { cn, formatNumberToCurrency } from "app/lib/utils";
import { ProposalServicesReducer, initialState } from "reducers/proposal-services-reducer";

export const createProposalSchema = z.object({
    // title: z.string(),
    // amount: z.string(),
    // description: z.string().optional(),
    // customerId: z.string(),
    // serviceAt: z.string(),
    services: z.array(z.any()),
});

interface ProposalModalProps {
    closeModal: () => void;
}
function ProposalModalCreateForm(props: ProposalModalProps) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [newCustomerName, setNewCustomerName] = useState<string>("");
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ProposalServicesReducer, initialState)

    const { data: customers = [] } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["customers"],
        queryFn: () => getCustomersQuery(),
    });

    const createCustomer = useMutation({
        mutationFn: createCustomerByName,
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["customers"] });
            setOpen(false)
        },
    });
    const createProposal = useMutation({
        mutationFn: createProposalMutation,
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["proposals"] });
        },
    });

    const { control, register, setValue, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useSlyderzForm(createProposalSchema, {
        title: "",
        services: [{ id: 1 }]
    });
    const { append, fields } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: "services"
    })

    const handleCreateCustomer = async () => {
        if (newCustomerName) {
            const res = await createCustomer.mutateAsync(newCustomerName);

            if (!res.success) {
                toast.error(res.error?.message);
            }

            return
        }

        toast.error("Customer name can't be empty");
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = async (input: FormData) => {
        const res = await createProposal.mutateAsync(input);

        if (!res.success) {
            toast.error(res.error?.message);
            return
        }

        toast.success("Proposal successfully created");
        props.closeModal();
    };
    const onSub = async (data: any) => {
        console.log(data)
        await createProposalMutation(data)
    }
    return (
        <FullScreenModal title="Create Proposal" formId="create-proposal-form">
            <div>
                <form
                    id="create-proposal-form"
                    action={handleFormSubmit}
                    // onSubmit={proposalForm.handleSubmit(onSub)}
                    className="space-y-8 overflow-auto"
                >
                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="customerId"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <div className="space-y-2 flex flex-col">
                                <input hidden name="customerId" value={field.value} />
                                <Label>Assign a customer to proposal</Label>
                                <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
                                    <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                                        <Button
                                            variant="outline"
                                            role="combobox"
                                            className={cn(
                                                "justify-between",
                                                !field.value && "text-muted-foreground",
                                            )}
                                        >
                                            {field.value
                                                ? customers.find(
                                                    (customer) => customer.id === field.value,
                                                )?.firstName
                                                : "Select customer"}
                                            <CaretSortIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
                                        </Button>
                                    </PopoverTrigger>
                                    <PopoverContent className="p-0 popover-content-width-full">
                                        <Command>
                                            <CommandInput
                                                placeholder="Search customers..."
                                                onKeyUp={(e: any) => setNewCustomerName(e.target.value)}
                                                required
                                            />
                                            <CommandList>
                                                <CommandEmpty>
                                                    <Button
                                                        variant="ghost"
                                                        className="w-full flex justify-start"
                                                        onClick={handleCreateCustomer}
                                                    >
                                                        <PlusIcon className={cn("h-5 w-5 font-bold pr-2")} />
                                                        <strong>
                                                            Create new customer: {newCustomerName}
                                                        </strong>
                                                    </Button>
                                                </CommandEmpty>
                                                <CommandGroup>
                                                    {customers.map((customer) => (
                                                        <CommandItem
                                                            {...field}
                                                            key={customer.id}
                                                            onSelect={() => {
                                                                setValue("customerId", customer.id);
                                                                setOpen(false);
                                                            }}
                                                            className="capitalize"
                                                        >
                                                            {customer?.firstName}
                                                            <CheckIcon
                                                                className={cn(
                                                                    "ml-auto h-4 w-4",
                                                                    customer.id === field.value
                                                                        ? "opacity-100"
                                                                        : "opacity-0",
                                                                )}
                                                            />
                                                        </CommandItem>
                                                    ))}
                                                </CommandGroup>
                                            </CommandList>
                                        </Command>
                                    </PopoverContent>
                                </Popover>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    />

                    <Separator />

                    <InputField
                        id="title"
                        label="Title"
                        placeholder="Proposal title"
                        {...register("title")}
                    />

                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="message"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <div className="space-y-2">
                                <Label>Message</Label>
                                <Textarea
                                    rows={3}
                                    placeholder="Thank you for choosing our services."
                                    {...field}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                    />
                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="serviceAt"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <div className="space-y-2">
                                <input hidden readOnly name="serviceAt" value={field.value} />
                                <Label>Service Date</Label>
                                <Popover>
                                    <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                                        <Button
                                            variant={"outline"}
                                            className={cn(
                                                "w-full pl-3 text-left font-normal",
                                                !field.value && "text-muted-foreground",
                                            )}
                                        >
                                            {field.value ? (
                                                format(field.value, "PPP")
                                            ) : (
                                                <span>Pick a date</span>
                                            )}
                                            <CalendarIcon className="ml-auto h-4 w-4 opacity-50" />
                                        </Button>
                                    </PopoverTrigger>
                                    <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0" align="start">
                                        <Calendar
                                            mode="single"
                                            selected={field.value}
                                            onSelect={field.onChange}
                                            // disabled={(date) => disableDaysOff(date)}
                                            initialFocus
                                        />
                                    </PopoverContent>
                                </Popover>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    />

                    <Separator />
                    <h6 className="text-lg font-semibold leading-none tracking-tight">
                        Services
                    </h6>

                    {/* <ServiceField
                        control={control}
                        register={register}
                        dispatch={dispatch}
                    /> */}
                    <button type="button" onClick={() => append({ id: 1 })}>
                        add service
                    </button>

                    {fields.map((f, i) => (
                        <input key={f.id} {...register(`services.${i}.id` as const)} />
                    ))}

                    {/* Proposal amount - hidden field */}
                    <input
                        {...register("amount" as const)}
                        hidden
                        readOnly
                        defaultValue={String(state.amount + 5.25)}
                    />
                </form>

                <section className="pt-10 w-full text-end gap-4 grid">
                    <p>
                        <strong>Subtotal:</strong> {formatNumberToCurrency(state.amount)}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Taxes:</strong> $5.25
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Total:</strong> {formatNumberToCurrency(state.amount + 5.25)}
                    </p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </FullScreenModal>
    );
}

export default ProposalModalCreateForm;



useFieldArray should be used with a name structured as "services". Then, register each item in the array as services[i].id, where i is the index.
React server actions expect data in a form-compatible format, so use JSON.stringify() to serialize the array and handle deserialization on the server.
